# SUM value from query changes when i add inner join to the query

Tags: php, sql, sum, inner-join

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT totals.*, sum(totals.payments) as total_payments
FROM totals
    INNER JOIN users
    GROUP BY totals.idseller;");
```

When i add the INNER JOIN the sum value is changed. Why?

In my SQL table i have one record in totals width this value: 8943.09   but when i do the some the result is giving me this value: 44715.45

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT totals.*, sum(totals.payments) as total_payments FROM totals
INNER JOIN users ON totals.idseller = users.idseller
GROUP BY users.UserName;");
```

Use this Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

When you INNER JOIN to another table, the returned data set is modified to only include rows that exist in both tables. In this case it is likely that there are rows in 'totals' that do not have a matching row in users - either the totals.idseller field might accept null values, or data has become orphaned when matching users have been deleted or edited.

If you want all data in 'totals' regardless of matching user you would user a LEFT JOIN instead in ms-sql, I suspect a similar approach will work in my-sql

Answer (score 0):

You should  give an "on" based on the ids. Such as like

```
inner join users on users.id = totals.idseller
```

Otherways the sql server will combine all possible rows in the tables, which is most cases not what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you are adding inner join in your SQL Query, it means you are selecting the data which is common in both the tables.
EX:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B 
ON TABLE_A.ID = TABLE_B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are joining users table which contains 5 records. By joining table, as there is no any column mapping, this sum-up 5 times and this is reason for showing different values.

Please let me know something wrong in it.

Thanks,
Umehs